# Importing full SVG with PDFKit

Tags: javascript, svg, pdfkit

Does anyone know if it's possible to import a full SVG into a PDFKit document? I can see from the docs that it has full SVG support, and there are methods for drawing paths etc, but I cannot see a method for importing a full SVG document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of V0.7 (Nov 2014), PDFKit does not support drawing SVG content to the PDF. Hovever, most of the building blocks are there (features covering most SVG presentations attributes + an SVG `path` parser), so implementing this would be a matter of traversing your SVG document tree from the root, keeping track of the transformation and attribute state (in case of inherited values) and drawing the SVG graphics primitives (including `path`s) you encounter. Of course some things like symbol definitions and filters would be more complicated to implement, but for basic geometry & styling this should not take longer than a few hours to implement given the features provided by PDFKit.

Comment: In the end I decided to go with using an API for my conversions, I am using CloudConvert who seem to be great so far. If anyone still needs this support in PDFKit, then like you say it doesn't sound like it would be overly complicated to add the feature and do a pull request.

Comment: I;m trying to build an interface between SVG and PDFKit, however I ran into a problem when using tranformations. The transformation matrix in pdf scales weirdly, can't find why... however when using `scale`, `rotate`... it works fine, will look into it, will let you know if I manage to make it work seamlessly

Comment: I tried to recreate my SVG in PDF using PDFKit, and finally i did it. **save()** and **restore()** methods becomes handy - firstly I saved state, then I copied every layer with transorm matrix calling restore() at the end. Note **transform** method, which is not documented in PDFKit, but it works (there are 6 vars - m11, m12, m21, m22, x, y)

Answer (score 19):

While searching for an answer to this question, I found a small open-source library that does the trick: [SVG-to-PDFKit](https://github.com/alafr/SVG-to-PDFKit).

If implementing your own interface is not convenient, this one is pretty easy to use (code sample from the Readme):

```
PDFDocument.prototype.addSVG = function(svg, x, y, options) {
  return SVGtoPDF(this, svg, x, y, options), this;
};
doc.addSVG(svg, x, y, options);
```

The parameters are as such:

> doc [PDFDocument] = the PDF document created with PDFKit
>
> svg [SVGElement or string] = the SVG object or XML code
>
> x, y [number] = the position where the SVG will be added

Check out the demo [here](https://alafr.github.io/SVG-to-PDFKit/examples/demo.htm).